# Update Manager getting errors

Tags: 12.04

I recently installed ChrUbuntu onto my Acer C7 Chromebook. I tried running the update manager from the terminal and I keep getting the same message

```
E: Malformed line 60 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Someone help me, I'm so new to Ubuntu.

Comment: This means that there's something wrong with your `sources.list` file at line 60. In a terminal, do `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`, copy the contents of the file, paste it in http://paste.ubuntu.com/, click "Paste!", and give us the URL of that page.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to generate [here](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) a new `sources.list` file and replace with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` that obviously have something wrong inside ("*The list of sources could not be read*").

See [here](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/01/restore-your-sources-list-to-defaults.html) how to replace `sources.list` with the new one.

More help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine.